# Playing with Geb in Groovy Console

Tags: groovy, geb

I am learning about GEB and i would like to play around with it in Groovy console. I am tying to run:

```
import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {
 go "http://googel.com/"
 assert title == "Google"
}
```

But this gives an error

```
unable to resolve class geb.Browser
 at line: 1, column: 1
```

I have downloaded Geb core jar (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.geb%7Cgeb-core%7C0.7.2%7Cjar) and put it in the PATH, but is not importing in the groovy console. What am i doing wrong and how  to run the simple Geb inline scripting?

Thank you

p.s. mac 10.7, geb 0.7.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting that at the top of your file :

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2"),//always use latest version of geb and selenium drivers
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.46.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.46.0")
])
```

Then, you won't have to deal with classpath issues and you'll got geb in groovy console easily

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Firefox pops up, but it won't actually navigate anywhere.

Comment: @RobertFischer It might be different issue, check if your firefox work with webdriver, and then try with geb. Alos check if U got latest driver version.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to wait for Selenium to come up with a new Firefox driver to match with my new Firefox version.